# GA4 and GTM events

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am sending custom events to GA4 from GTM. I have created custom dimensions/definitions in GA4 so I can see my custom event parameters from GTM in my event reports.

I am running into an issue where I am seeing unrelated custom dimensions/definitions on events.

Here is an example

### **GTM Event config:**

[GTM - GA Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqr4b.png)

[GTM Event - "Header -Custom Event1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0hC9.png)

[GTM Trigger - "Just header links"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWLpo.png)

[GTM Event - "Updated Footer - Custom Event 2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6uqh.png)

[GTM Trigger - "Just footer links"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzHmO.png)

**Event Name: Updated_Header_Menu_event**

Event Parameters

Updated_PagePath1 : {{Page Path}}

Updated_Hostname1 : {{Page Hostname}}

**Event Name: Updated_Footer_Menu_event**

Event Parameters

Updated_Footer_Menu_event : {{Page Path}}

Updated_Hostname2 : {{Page Hostname}}

### **GA4 Config**

In GA4 I have created custom definitions for each of the parameters, e.g.

[GA - Custom definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Ys6.png)

[GA - "Updated Header_Menu_event" with unrelated definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LxFZ.png)

Dimension Name: Updated Click Text 1
Parameter: Updated_Click_Text_1

Dimension Name: Updated_Click_Text_2
Parameter: Updated_Click_Text_2

The issue is when I click on the "Updated_Header_Menu_event" event, I see the definitions for "Updated_Header_Menu_event" parameters, but also the definitions for "Updated_Footer_Menu_event". Why am I seeing definitions (i.e. the cards) for events that don't contain the parameters for those definitions?

I expect to only see definitions for events that contain the parameters for those definitions

Comment: Maybe you can upload the screenshot from the GTM : GA4 event setting and configuration setting. Also the GA4 custom definition and the card you saw.

Comment: @darrelltw -- thanks for the suggestion. I added screenshots of the configuration on GA & GTM

Comment: Looks strange. Can you take the screenshot from the `GA4 config tag`. It is the tag you set in the `GA4 event tag`. Maybe it is already being configured for all parameters.

Comment: @darrelltw I added a screenshot of the GA4 tag in GTM and the GA4event settings in the tag. If you were asking for something else let me know.

Comment: Thanks.  All the setting seems no significant mistake. Is the setting publish to the users? Maybe we can check today or yesterday's number to see if everything if fine now. From the screenshot you provided. It's one user who triggered the click ten times. Not sure if this is coming from testing and on that time the setting is not right but fixed after.

Comment: @darrelltw, the user is me that is setting off the event--I'm trying to debug the reason the definitions are showing. They are still showing today after more testing. Is there anything else you recommend I look at?

Comment: If you can share the GTM preview link. You can find how to contact in my profile and message the link to me. I can help to investigate if there is issue when previewing. Or maybe share the GTM read permission to me.